# Create event bridge rule on event bridge bus on non default using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-event-bridge

I want to provision an event bridge bus with a single rule on the the non default bus. I have the following terraform code.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
       version = ">= 5.31.0"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_bus" "event_bridge_bus" {
    name = "my-event-bridge-bus2"
}


# Event Rule to capture events from S3 bucket
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "event_rule" {
    depends_on = [aws_cloudwatch_event_bus.event_bridge_bus]
    name        = "my-event-rule"
    description = "Event rule for capturing events from S3 bucket"
    event_bus_name = aws_cloudwatch_event_bus.event_bridge_bus.arn

    event_pattern = <<PATTERN
{
    "source": ["aws.s3"],
    "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
    "detail": {
        "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
        "eventName": ["PutObject", "DeleteObject"]
    }
}
PATTERN
}
```

However when I do the terraform apply it get's put on the `default` event bus

Comment: Shouldn't it be `event_bus_name = aws_cloudwatch_event_bus.event_bridge_bus.name` instead of `.arn`?

Comment: @MarkB Not in this case. From [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_rule#event_bus_name): The name or ARN of the event bus to associate with this rule. If you omit this, the default event bus is used.

Comment: @Marcin sorry my bad. The problem is that it was being put on the default bus. Have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is **nothing wrong** with the code that you provided. It works exactly as expected, which means that the code that generates the error is different then in the question.